# @ManyToMany relationship in spring boot?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have the following line in my "User" class :

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "members")
private List<Community> communities = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I have the following line in the "Community" class :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable
private List<User> members;
```

I am trying to make it so that a user can "Create" a community, and then have that user appear as a member of said new community.

Here is the code where I create the community...

```
public ResponseEntity<?> newCommunity(@Valid @RequestBody NewCommunityRequestPayload newCommunityrequest) {

    // Get current user.
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    // New list of users here, since it is a new community.
    List<User> members = new ArrayList<>();

    User currentUser;
    if (principal instanceof User){
        currentUser = ((User)principal);

        // Add this user to the member list.
        members.add(currentUser);

        // create a new Community object.
        Community newCommunity = new Community();

        // Set the name, and set the member list.
        newCommunity.setCommunityName(newCommunityRequest.getCommunityName());
        newCommunity.setMembers(members);

        Community result = communityRepository.save(newCommunity);

        return new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(true, "Created new community."),
                HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
    return new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(false, "Invalid user object"),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

As mentioned, I am trying to make it so that a user can "Create" a community, and then have that user appear as a member of said new community... When I save the community above, it is saved in the db, and a table is generated by hibernate for the relationship, but there is no row in there for that. How do I fix that?

Comment: please add the number of tables that you added for project

Comment: Can you specify your question?

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal Omg, I totally passed out from exhaustion and forgot to add the real question... I will do that now!

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Comment: @PauloPedroso - Yeah... That's where I got my code to begin with. It doesn't work.